# How to make Eden Space size double Tenured Space

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-hotspot

Is there any way to make the Eden space proportionally bigger than Tenured? There is `NewRatio` but it works the other way (Tenured is that times bigger than Eden).

I know there is `-XX:NewSize=` and `-XX:OldSize=` but I was looking for something similar to mentioned ratio parameter (which would give more flexibility).

I've tried using fraction but it's not valid value.

Comment: which java version are you using ? please check here  [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Comment: Mostly 8. I've already seen this page but I haven't found anything which could be related.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the total heap size (with -Xms and -Xmx) it is possible to explicitly set a lower and upper bound for the size of the young generation. However, when setting -XX:MaxNewSize we need to take into account that the young generation is only one part of the heap and that the larger we choose its size the smaller the old generation will be. `For stability reasons it is not allowed to choose a young generation size larger than the old generation, because in the worst case it may become necessary for a GC to move all objects from the young generation into the old generation. Thus -Xmx/2 is an upper bound for -XX:MaxNewSize.`

For performance reasons we may also specify the initial size of the young generation using the flag -XX:NewSize. This is useful if we know the rate at which young objects are being allocated (for example because we measured it!) and can save some of the costs required for slowly growing the young generation to that size over time.

My answer is based on [this](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/08/useful-jvm-flags-part-5-young-generation-garbage-collection/) blog.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - as I already mentioned in the OP I am aware of -XX:MaxNewSize and -XX:NewSize -- but those require concrete sizes instead of ratios referencing defined HeapSize

Comment: yes,..I got your point, but actually in your question, you have asked about to make the eden space greater in size than tenured, which I think is not possible as per above answer. Also, can you tell me a little bit about your exact requirement/situation, may be then I can answer you better.

Comment: Well, actually it is possible and I'm running JVM with such settings (765M Eden vs 256M Tenured). The thing is - the system at hand generates a lot of short lived objects, and theory says that those should be confined to Eden space while tenured should only have long-lived objects -- collecting Eden space in MinorGC, while all objects in Eden are collectable is super-fast (all things considered) thus it would be super helpful to simply configure the system that the Eden should be 3 or 4 times the size of Tenured space, which would make away the whole hassle of putting exact values in the conf.

Comment: @Wojtek: did you ever *measure* whether your setup produces a real performance improvement? There is a much easier way to get rid of these exact values in the conf, just remove them *without any replacement*.

Comment: @Holger yes, yes... and they result in Eden roughtly 60M and the rest of the 1G heap being Tenured space clogged with prematurely promoted short lived objects which then result in longer FullGC pauses... I haven't asked for verification of this setup - only for configuration option!

Comment: @Wojtek: I’m not surprised that you didn’t mention an actual performance improvement. As you said in the other comment “*theory says that those should be* …”. A full gc on a Tenured space full of “short lived objects” doesn’t differ significantly from a local gc on a larger Eden space, as both have in common, that unreachable objects have no impact on the performance. If there are longer pauses, it implies, that the objects are not short lived.